# How to configure QProgressDialog to not close

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, user-interface

My problem is when I click on cancel button the QProgressDialog closed and I send to task a message to cancel, but while my task running the MainWindow stay locked. Is there a option do not close QProgressDialog while my task do not receive cancel message?

```
progressDialog->setMaximum(0);
progressDialog->setMinimum(0);
progressDialog->setWindowTitle(QString::fromStdString(title));
progressDialog->setLabelText(QString::fromStdString(text));

QFutureWatcher<void> futureWatcher;
QObject::connect(&futureWatcher, SIGNAL(finished()), progressDialog.get(), SLOT(reset()));
QObject::connect(progressDialog.get(), SIGNAL(canceled()), this, SLOT(cancel()));
QObject::connect(progressDialog.get(), SIGNAL(canceled()), &futureWatcher, SLOT(cancel()));

// Start the computation.
futureWatcher.setFuture(QtConcurrent::run(func));

// Display the dialog and start the event loop.
progressDialog->exec();
futureWatcher.waitForFinished();
```

Thank's

Comment: so you just want the dialog to stat on the screen ... surely if you dont click cancel the dialog doesnt close?

Comment: Yes, at the end dialog close, but if I click cancel the dialog close and my func (QtConcurrent::run(func)) still running and block QtMainWindow.

Comment: I created a repository with this problem [repository - github](https://github.com/fleith/waitingdlg). When run application end click cancel button the mainwindow still blocked.